# Breishit 24:65 - Yitchak is Eliezer's master?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-chaye-sara

In Breishit 24:65, Eliezer refers to Yitchak as "my master". Why is that? Isn't Avraham his master?

Perhaps, this is was considered parlance of that time. But, throughout his conversation with Betu'el, he refers to Avraham as his master and, while never mentioning the name Yitzchak, he refers to him as "the son of my master" (See verse 24 as an example.) So, why, here, does he refer to Yitzhak as "my master" instead of as "my master's son"?

Answer (score 5):

I've wondered the same thing.  This is my best attempt, but I don't have a source for it.

In pasuk 10, Rashi says that Eliezer brought with him a document that Avraham had signed, giving all of his possessions to Yitzchak.  That would include Eliezer himself.  While he was looking for a wife for Yitzchak, he was still fulfilling his original command from Avraham, and so it still made sense to refer to Avraham as "his master".  Once the mission was done, Yitzchak was his new master.

Comment: Gee. This makes a lot of sense. I'd love to see a source to support this so I can definitely accept this answer.

Comment: @DanF - I was going to answer the same thing. :)

Comment: @ezra You know the rule. The one who finishes the mitzvah gets credit for the whole thing. Well, it doesn't work that way on this site, though :-( But you can edit the above by providing a source to support Heshy's claim.

Comment: Minchas Asher Bereishis 27:7 is addressing how could Eliezer be a shliach for Kiddushin, when the gemarra says a slave can't do that. He quotes the Panim Yafos at the beginning of Chayei Sarah who says if it's your own slave it's fine, since yad eved keyad rabo. Rav Asher asks but the Kiddushin is for Yitzchak and Eliezer belonged to Avraham. Rav Asher answers it's because of that Rashi you quote, that Avraham gave his servant to Yitzchak.

Comment: @robev This is certainly good source support to the above. You should make this an answer - either your won or added to this one.

Comment: I don't know why Eliezer still calls Avraham his master, unless we use what Heshy suggests